# Failing to start nginx container when volumes is used (using ansible and docker-compose)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ansible

I am trying to start an nginx container using ansible with docker-compose from one machine to a different machine.

Whenever I include nginx.conf to the volumes, there is an error which I do not understand. **The container is only created but not starting.**

MACHINE-1

Command to run the playbook: `ansible-playbook -v nginx-playbook.yml -l ubuntu_node_1 -u root`

my playbook:

```
- name: nginx-docker_compose
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - community.general.docker_compose:
        project_name: nginx
        definition:
          version: '2'
          services:
            web:
              image: nginx:latest
              volumes:
                - ./vars/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
              ports:
                - "8080:80"
```

[EDITED]

Here is the error:

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [nginx-docker_compose] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 18.04 on host 172.31.15.176 should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior
Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [172.31.15.176]

TASK [community.general.docker_compose] ********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.31.15.176]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "errors": [], "module_stderr": "Recreating nginx_web_1 ... \n\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\nRecreating nginx_web_1 ... \n\u001b[1B", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "Error starting project Encountered errors while bringing up the project."}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.31.15.176              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

[root@ip-172-31-12-130 docker_server]# ansible-playbook -v nginx-playbook.yml -l ubuntu_node_1 -u root
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [nginx-docker_compose] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 18.04 on host 172.31.15.176 should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior
Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [172.31.15.176]

TASK [community.general.docker_compose] ********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.31.15.176]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "errors": [], "module_stderr": "Recreating 9b102bbf98c2_nginx_web_1 ... \n\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\nRecreating 9b102bbf98c2_nginx_web_1 ... \n\u001b[1B", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "Error starting project Encountered errors while bringing up the project."}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.31.15.176              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**NOTE: When I try to run nginx container directly using docker-compose with the same config on MACHINE-2, it works.
I believe there are some permission issues happening while trying to execute the playbook from MACHINE-1 to MACHINE-2 but can not figure it out.**

Comment: Be aware that unless you have a `./vars/nginx.conf` copied to the working directory on the destination machine, that will not do what you are expecting; just because the file exists in your playbook does not mean it exists on the destination host without putting it there (in fact, the best possible outcome is a full path for a volume mount, due to the way docker works)

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for this missing information. It works now.
Things I changed:
1. I wrote the entire directory in the playbook- /home/some_more_folders/nginx.conf
2. and copied the same file with same directory structure on the destination machine.

Could you please tell me where this info is documented on ansible or docker page? 
And also, any idea why is it necessary to copy any file to the destination machine (such as nginx.conf)?

Answer (score 0):

It works now. Thanks to @mdaniel.

Things I changed:

1. I wrote the entire directory in the playbook- /home/some_more_folders/nginx.conf
2. and copied the same file with same directory structure on the destination machine.

Still open questions:

1. Any idea why is it necessary to copy any file to the destination machine (such as nginx.conf)?
2. How this manual process of copying of config files to destination machine for docker-compose be automated?